# Typescript - index signatures with generically typed functions

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in Typescript to define an interface with an index signature where the values of the properties referred by the index are different types of the same generic type?

Let me try to explain:

I have a function Foo with the following generic signature:

```
interface Foo<T> {(arg1: Moo<T>): T}
interface Moo<N> {nest: N}
```

And then an object that will consist of a bunch of functions of type Foo, but each one with different generic parameters.  So:

```
interface Foos {
    bar: Foo<number>,
    baz: Foo<string>
}

const foos:Foos = {
    bar: x => x.nest,
    baz: y => y.nest
}
```

But I don't want to have to define each function explicitly in the interface.  I want something like:

```
interface FoosTwo {[K:string]: Foo<any>}

const foosTwo:FoosTwo = {
    bar: x => x.nest,
    baz: y => y.nest
}
```

But of course, if I do that, I've lost any sort of real typing on foosTwo.bar and foosTwo.baz -- they are both just `Foo<any>`.  Which makes sense--how would the compiler know what I wanted?

But is there someway to tell the compiler what the generic type of Foo will be, inline, i.e., something like this (which I realize doesn't work)?

```
interface FoosTwo {[K:string]: Foo<any>}

const foosTwo:FoosTwo = {
    bar<number>: x => x.nest,
    baz<string>: y => y.nest
}
```

In other words, is there some way to give the compiler just enough information to figure out that bar is `Foo<number>` and baz is `Foo<string>` without needing to explicitly define the full type for every function?

Much appreciated

Comment: Not sure if helps, but same approach as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63777650/1113002. Try on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHt0B4ByA+ZAb2RAgGcwAuZHZAXwChRJZEUAxTLAFQOIAo4UAOYBGahmy8AlNW70GDBOhAVkCKBDiRO6MsgC8yHsggAPSCAAm+gEoRlUK1gpRQwgDTJdWOCACeeEH8MJhkctKGBKF6ANyKyqpgyDFk3ADu6IbqmtoQumT8hAzIpcgARkLU-GYSXK7ueJEGBGYAdKQUHiVllQBe1f512CAArgC25dBNUcj+HeRgDHTS8UA)

Comment: Yes, your and @jonrsharpe's comments on that post opened my eyes a bit on the index strings.  I will play with it a little and see if that gives me the solution I need here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the advice from @aleksey-l above, I now see the solution is trivial.

Thinking about it as a question of index signatures (which is what I was doing) is wrong.  Index signatures like [K:string] or Record(string, any) are necessarily loose in that they have to be the same for anything that satisfies the signatures.  Which is why the best I could do was `interface FoosTwo {[K:string]: Foo<any>}`.

What it turns out I really wanted TS to do was *infer* a strongly typed interface like the manual one I set out above:

```
interface Foos {
    bar: Foo<number>,
    baz: Foo<string>
}
```

And the way to do that is to use an identity function and generics to have TS basically suck in some typing information and then use that to type the final function.  So this:

```
function createFoo<T>(func: Foo<T>):Foo<T> {
    return func
}

const foosTwo = {
    bar: createFoo<number>(x => x.nest),
    baz: createFoo<string>( y => y.nest)
}
```

A simple identity function that uses the "hint" provided by the generic to type the returned (identical) function in the way I want.  @alexksey-l's solution works just as well though it's formulated a little differently than I put the question.  He gets the credit for the answer (and for opening my eyes to some of the power of using generics).

Here's [a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA%20ZAbwAo4oBzARgC5kBZTXPASlpwF8AoUSWRFBtgByBQiAgBnMLSFdOAennIA8lGDlQcADbIAClHQAjLRAC2tABLoA7sjDpkELcFObIyU3BABXbVoCeCkoIUBBwYKDkdgAWwBJomPE80PBIAPzc4Cn8CejxhJzIRciGZLQY2D6mhtB4ADSFxaUAXuWMUmog5HiccgjoIFLIMInUFfEAvESNRaVQtAAeyBMECwB04lINxSVwrcj%20ywT%20G5JgvZxByACCg9bQtACqEiheyMAAJhDgwDCHMN4QAgIgNkNZgGBoshyN9oMAEBJOACgSCQMgQmFIBUmMRkQg2th8KxsfhpjtQmBvFA0XiLpx%20oMwMNEjhrA4pgUdnNaBjwhBsVUalA8MQlitkOtNmBmNsmnseaE%20diOpERQcjgdTlJmL0gA) with the full solution.

Answer (score -1):

One option:

```
const foosTwo = {
    bar: (x => x.nest) as Foo<number>,
    baz: (y => y.nest) as Foo<string>
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was hoping to avoid casting if it's possible.  This object will have functions added to it by different developers and I would rather have the function interface inferred than relying on people to provide the correct cast.  That said, I do think this is an improvement.