# Typescript - Union constraint causes unwanted type widening

Tags: typescript

Another inference question.  I'm trying to prevent Typescript from losing properly inferred type information when I have a union type buried in an object.  Here's the situation:

Two interfaces--Foo and Moo--and their union FooMoo:

```
interface Foo { goo: string}
interface Moo { goo: number}
type FooMoo = Foo | Moo

const foo: Foo = {goo: "bar"}
const moo: Moo = {goo: 1}
```

And a mixed object that contains (at least) one of each:

```
const mixedObject = {
    foo,
    moo
}
```

Now, obviously, TS knows the correct types of foo and moo, so no problem here:

```
let fooToo: Foo
let mooToo: Moo

fooToo = mixedObject.foo
mooToo = mixedObject.moo
```

But now let's say I want to tell TS that mixedObject should be limited to *only* foos and moos.  Well, that restriction apparently causes TS to lose its ability to discriminate between foo and moo, so the following code errors:

```
type ManyFooMoos = {[K:string]: FooMoo}
const mixedObjectToo: ManyFooMoos = {
    foo,
    moo
}

// TS errors here because it can't narrow foo to Foo and moo to Moo;
// it just knows they are both FooMoos
fooToo = mixedObjectToo.foo
mooToo = mixedObjectToo.moo
```

This same thing can come up in other ways where the constraint on mixedObject that causes TS to lose information is more indirect.  For example:

```
interface ExportedObject {
    manyFooMoos: ManyFooMoos
} 

const exportedObject: ExportedObject = {
    manyFooMoos: mixedObject
}

fooToo = exportedObject.manyFooMoos.foo
```

So, my basic question is -- how can I *keep* the constraint on mixedObject (i.e., that all it's properties must be Foos or Moos) without *losing* the specific types of those Foos or Moos within mixedObject?

The full code is on [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7IOaYBcyAzmFKHgL4BQoksiKAspjvkciAK4C2ARtFpgAngAcUGdKywBeNGwA%20yGTRoJ0IMshicpyedgLpiAIn5wop2hq1hkvTjIM5jxAIy11m7b2AAPCAATAHl%20ACsIBHtDGmR4nUwAGjiEx3QaLwAbCHtddAAVPUwaHPt0opMVEpoAelrkAoBlZABrEHQAdxJErGAe-TgQIIc2fuqM-MqXP0DQiKiwADp8mgq2eVngsMjopfS1euQAYR9yOFBkMAALcfQF6NI%20sB7QIIg55DEodAkoMGAEB6CCGyAA%20posiIwXUGoIFOgeugoBMSDRRBIVEMRFIZD1DABtADShDIFBAeAAusRcZgbGcHAFtg8wJViMxsbTES5sKl4vkUglRhkvEcAELcewdTqNFrXOA9LKI%20w3FCgXRQXhwAGaZC6zrXXKGqCw3rIcZwBF6lHpc09S0yJbxACS9khIja0p6qo9lggpv46BuCLxNCmG0Zcx2i0qKxK6zkkeZu1ZmH2NSOzqyWW4ZO1lCuhtIcF4KFsefoyH4kuQnWAwctJCywDw1zAUNNORIPQ%20YmbCHrtbgHvQMHNvD7EFL4EodHA0HgSGQAFF-GJkZB5imcHyHJzMHj2fvpJg0VRkGpy-Zexvk4tiKv1-8749YkKtSAcQfT8QtlvFpkhwNAAgsMhYoCQJYoNAPxQEs8Fhpg0zyDez7-nsH5fieiJxhkQA).

Comment: You can't, that's what's supposed to happen. You no longer get the inferred type, you're accessing it through a mapping of string to Foo *or* Moo.

Comment: Why is that?  In other words, why does that fact that I'm accessing it through a string index cause TS to lose the inference?  That doesn't happen when I access it through the unconstrained object "mixedObject"--which is also a string index, albeit a string literal.

Comment: Because the inferred ("unconstrained") type is `{ foo: Foo, moo: Moo }`, which *is narrower* than the explicit `{ [key: string]: Foo | Moo }`. It doesn't lose the inference accidentally, *you did that*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using identity function + generics. This will allow to keep the constraint and prevent type widening:

```
const createFooMoos = <T extends ManyFooMoos>(fooMoos: T) => fooMoos;

const mixedObjectToo = createFooMoos({
    foo,
    moo
}) // { foo: Foo, moo: Moo }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7IOaYBcyAzmFKHgL4BQoksiKAspjvkciAK4C2ARtFpgAngAcUGdKywBeNGwA+yGTRoJ0IMshicpyedgLpiAIn5wop2hq1hkvTjIM5jxAIy11m7b2AAPCAATAHl+ACsIBHtDGmR4nUwAGjiEx3QaLwAbCHtddAAVPUwaHPt0opMVEpp8ypc-QNCIqLAAOnyaCrZ5RuCwyOi29LUAelHkAGEfcjhQZDAAC2ASZHQW6NIsYDBV0CCIJuQxKHQJKDBgCFWEOBBkAH1NLJEHmnHkQQV0VfQoap+NFEEhUdxEUhkq0MAG0ANKEMgUEB4AC6xAhmBsM2QCCgEDgkAxPxcAB4CshDpAQEFVswwUSSAA+AAU+UhxAKAEoDIzEtJMCQANzeOwOAL9DZgeryXH4wmYSHM7CpeL5FIJBwlKictR1HpipoDVqVDolbpyA0SwZSzDDGq2bSHMR-SDNa0uZUa3j0hUC4h9N2tTK6zDSin+Z0XK2tYY+-k-U0ZIA)

Comment: Just so I make sure I understand--this solution works because it is basically overcoming the problem that @jonrsharpe pointed out, i.e., that ManyFooMoos is _less_ precise than the inferred type of mixedObjectToo.  But what this does is say, use the specific type of mixedObjectToo (i.e., T) as long as it extends the more general type ManyFooMoos.  So now my inferred type of mixedObjectToo _is_ the more specific type, but it also follows the constraint of the extends clause.  Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, constraint is applied to function parameter, so you can pass only something that "extends" `ManyFooMoos`. On the other hand the passed parameter type is inferred (due to generics) and is used as a return type